# Maximum of $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{\mu(n)}{n}x^n$, $0<x<1$, where $\mu(n)$ is the Möbius function

Tags: sequences-and-series, analytic-number-theory, maxima-minima, mobius-function

Let $\mu(n)$ the Möbius function,
 see it definition in this [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%B6bius_function), and we define for $0<x<1$ $$f(x):=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{\mu(n)}{n}x^n.\tag{1}$$

This morning I was drawing with the help of [Wolfram Alpha online calculator](https://www.wolframalpha.com/) some graphs for $$f_N(x):=\sum_{n=1}^N\frac{\mu(n)}{n}x^n$$ and their derivatives. Play with  these codes for different values of $N=2000,5000,..,10000$:

`plot sum mu(n)/n t^n, from n=1 to 10000, for 0<t<1`

`plot sum mu(n) t^(n-1), from n=1 to 5000, for 0<t<1`

`plot sum (n-1)mu(n) t^(n-2), from n=1 to 5000, for 0<t<1`

From this experiments, and since we know the derivative test, see this [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derivative_test) I believe that the function $f(x)$ defined in $(1)$ for $0<x<1$ has a maximum around at $x\approx 0.6$.

> **Question.** Is it possible to prove that $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{\mu(n)}{n}x^n,$$ defined for reals $0<x<1$, has such maximum in this interval? **Many thanks.**

---

**Appendix.** Similar experiments can be done with other arithmetic function, and closely related, the Liouville function

`plot sum LiouvilleLambda(n)/n t^n, from n=1 to 1000, for 0<t<1`

and the difference between both functions:

`plot sum (mu(n)-LiouvilleLambda(n))/n t^n, from n=1 to 5000, for 0<t<1`

Comment: You merely want to prove the existence of the maximum?  Just check end points to see they aren't the maximum, and since the function is continuous....

Comment: I accept your words, many thanks. Any case I hope some hours if some user want to provide an answer @SimplyBeautifulArt . That is. I prefer a more detailed study of such maximum.

Comment: $x\approx 0.6$? Then I'd bet that $x=\frac{\sqrt 5-1}2$.

Comment: Look at $\sum_{n=N}^\infty \frac{x^n}{\ln^k n}$ and use the bounds $|\sum_{n= N}^\infty \frac{\mu(n)}{n}| < \frac{C}{\ln^k N}$ from the PNT

Comment: I don't know @HagenvonEitzen , in any case, bet accepted! I don't know if this exercise was in the literature but seem interesting. Many thanks for your attention.

Comment: @user1952009 add a detailed answer please. I hope you are well.

Comment: Hm, bet lost. Seems the zero of $\sum \mu(n)x^n$ is below $.6$

Answer (score 0):

$$f(x) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\mu(n)}{n}x^n, \qquad f_N(x) = \sum_{n=1}^N \frac{\mu(n)}{n}x^n$$ 
We have the trivial bound $|f(x)-f_N(x)| < \frac{1}{1-x^N}$

And the same for the derivatives, so the behavior on $[0,a],a < 1$ is not complicated, and we can evaluate numerically and find the maximum an minimum.

The problem is to show $\lim_{x \to 1} f(x) =0$ and to find a bound of the form $|f(x)| < \frac{A}{|\ln(1-x)|}$.

To achieve this, use the summation by parts, some bounds for $(1-x)\sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac{x^n}{\ln^k n}$ and the PNT in the form $|\sum_{n= N}^\infty \frac{\mu(n)}{n}| < \frac{C}{\ln^k N}$ (that's the complicated part).

Once this is done, you'll get that the minimum and maximum is in $[0,a]$ for some $ a < 1$ and you'll be able to evaluate it numerically.

Comment: Many thanks for your attention and answer.